# Creating Member Variables/datasets in Wix & javascript

Tags: javascript, velo

I'm trying to create a credits system specific to a single user within my website with wix but I can't seem to find any way of associating a variable or dataset with a single account that can take away credits when used. Its my first time using wix and Im not sure if this is possible.

Tried currentMember.getmember() for which there was no reference on the velo page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is quite general, I will give you a general answer.

The basic idea is to create a collection with a field that references one of the member collections. That will associate each item in your collection with a specific user. Then you can keep track of credits using your collection.